# LINQ GroupBy and Distinct

Tags: c#, linq

I am trying to get a set of records that match certain criteria.
Imagine I have a list of orders, each with a nested account, a bit like this:

```
var orders = [{
    account: {
        id: 1
    }
}, {
    account: {
        id: 1
    }
}, {
    account: {
        id: 2
    }
}, {
    account: {
        id: 2
    }
}, {
    account: {
        id: 1
    }
}, {
    account: {
        id: 4
    }
}, {
    account: {
        id: 3
    }
}];
```

I would like to use LINQ to get all the distinct accounts based on the account id.
I thought I might be able to do something like:

```
var accounts = results.Select(m => m.Account).GroupBy(m => m.AccountNumber).Distinct();
```

but that doesn't appear to work.
Can someone help me out?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
var accounts = results
              .Select(m => m.Account)
              .GroupBy(m => m.AccountNumber)
              .Select(x => x.First());
```

and better, implement `IEquatable<T>` in Account class:

```
class Account : IEquatable<Account> 
{
    public int AccountNumber { get; set; }

    // more members....

    public bool Equals(Account another) => this.AccountNumber == another.AccountNumber;
    public override int GetHashCode() => this.AccountNumber;
}
```

then simple and effective:

```
results.Select(m => m.Account).Distinct();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
results.Select(m => m.Account).GroupBy(m => m.AccountNumber)
                          .Select(g => g.First()).ToList()
```